# AsyncStorage's getItem reset the array each time the setItem is called in React Native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Hello **( I'm sorry in advance for the long introduction )**,
so I'm making this workout app in React Native where you can take notes of your exercises each day of the week ( it works like a todo app ).
The homepage just contains the 7 days of the weeks. When you click on any day, you get directed on its page ( workout.js ) where you can add a new exercise to it. When you finish to add your exercise(s) to this day you save it and get redirected on the information page ( information.js ) where the exercises you previously added are listed ( it's suppose to be a page where you can see all the exercises of all the days you added like a todo app ).
So to make it all work, I used AsyncStorage's setItem and getItem.

The problem is that every time you add a new exercise on a different day, the exercises you previously saved get replaced with this new exercise when I want it to get added like a list of the exercises of each day. I think it's something about either the setData or the getData function but I don't know how to fix it.

I put a setItem in the workout page where you add your exercises of the day :

```
const [exercises, setExercises] = useState([])
  const setData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('exercises', JSON.stringify(exercises))
      navigation.navigate('Informations')
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
```

and to retrieve it on the information page, I put a getItem where all the exercises of any day are supposed to be shown :

```
const [exercises, setExercises] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('exercises')
      if (data !== null) {
        setExercises(JSON.parse(data))
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
```

This is how I add exercises in the array in the workout file :

```
  const addExercises = (exercise) => {
    exercise.key = Math.random().toString()
    setExercises((currentExercise) => {
      return [exercise, ...currentExercise]
    })
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible)
  }
```

I'm sorry if it's not quite understandable ( I don't know if images could be useful ).
If you need the entire code of certain pages or more details to understand, please tell me.

Thank's in advance for any potential response.

Comment: how do you add an exercise to the exercises array in the state?

Comment: I edited my post with the addExercises function